# Derivation of the following Taylor series?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The book that I am reading skips a lot of details which is both good and bad. Now I am in the case where it is bad :P I am currently reading about numerical integration and specifically the Simpson's rule:

$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx \simeq \frac{b-a}{2}(f(a) + 4f(\frac{a+b}{2}) + f(b))
$$

I will now show the parts that confuses me:
[image]

[image]

So my questions are:

1. Can someone explain/elaborate how the Taylor series from the first image is derived exactly(like showing steps)? I have tried but cannot figure it out.
2. In the second image, I get the part of fundamental calculus of course, but again, can you elaborate on how the Taylor series is derived by maybe showing steps? I do think that I can figure out how to combine them if I get that far :)

I have somehow managed to spend 2 hours just trying to figure this out. :(

Comment: I'll never, ever understand why people too lazy to format their questions nicely expect others not to be too lazy to answer (with nicely formatted answers, naturally). Why can't there be a process to reject or delete such questions automatically?!

Comment: @Moo Uhhh, that looks interesting! I'll take a look :)

Comment: @Moo I was interesting but sadly it is not really the same formulas as I see it.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Will you calm down? It's not such a huge deal....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really is just grind & bookkeeping.

Also, there is a typo., the $23$ should be  ${2 \over 3}$.

For simplicity I am assuming that $f$ is real analytic, the following analysis is similar if $f$ is just $k$ times differentiable, but involves more detail.

Let $c(h) = f(a)+4 f(a+h) + f(a+2h)$, then $c(0) = 6 f(a)$ and
$c^{(k)}(0) = (4+2^k) f^{(k)}(a)$.

So, we get ${h \over 3} c(h) = 2f(a)h + \sum_{k \ge 2} {1 \over 3 (k-1)!} (4+2^{k-1}) f^{(k-1)}(a) h^k$.

Now let $d(h) = \int_a^{a+2h}f(x)dx$, then $d(0) = 0$ and $d^{(k)}(0) = 2^k f^{(k-1)}(a)$ and so
$d(h) = 2f(a)h+ \sum_{k \ge 2} {1 \over k!} 2^k f^{(k-1)}(a) h^k$.

If you grind through the numbers, the coefficients of $1,h,h^2,h^3,h^4$ are the same, but the coefficients of $h^5$ are ${5 \over 18} f^{(4)}(a)$ and
${4 \over 15} f^{(4)}(a)$ for $c,d$ respectively.

Hence we have $c(h)-d(h) = ({5 \over 18} - {4 \over 15}) f^{(4)}(a) h^5 + \cdots = -{1 \over 90} f^{(4)}(a) h^5 + \cdots$.

Comment: Wutttttttttttt. You did it! Thanks!!!! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Oh wait, but how did you get that $c^{(k)}(0) = (4+2^k) f^{(k)}(a)$_

Comment: Just keep differentiating, see the pattern, then confirm with induction.